# using CreateNames for sheet-only names vba

Tags: excel, range, vba

I am using

```
ActiveCell.CurrentRegion.CreateNames top:=True, left:=False
```

this is effective in naming the columns at the top. I need to make these named ranges local to the sheet. Is there a way to do this with the CreateNames instead of the Names.Add?

Any help would be much appreciate.

Comment: + 1 Good Question. But I am not sure as to why do you not want to use `Names.Add`

Answer (score 2):

By default the scope of Names created by `CreateNames` is 'Workbook'

You mean like this?

```
ActiveCell.CurrentRegion.Name = ActiveSheet.Name & "!" & _
                                ActiveCell.Offset(-1).Value
```

The logic is to directly name it using the Activesheet's name so that the scope remain to that relevant sheet. Also I am using `.Offset` to compensate for `top:=True`. You will have to change that accordingly.

You could also use

```
ActiveCell.CurrentRegion.Name = ActiveSheet.Name & "!" & _
                                Range(ActiveCell.CurrentRegion.Address).Cells(1, 1).Value
```

We need to understand that `top:=True` will create names by using labels in the top row. So I am assuming that the first cell has Text Values.

Comment: Note that `.CreateNames` behaviour does not include label cells in named range - you must apply `.Name` to `.CurrentRegion` except label cells.